# Are all questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I came upon this question: [How does SVN store identical text files in different sub-directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38885924/how-does-svn-store-identical-text-files-in-different-sub-directories)

Sure enough, SVN is definitely a tool commonly used by programmers. A question asking "How to do a checkout with SVN" or "How to branch with SVN" would definitely be on-topic. But this question has, in my opinion, nothing to do with any practical programming problem, and I voted to close it. Was I wrong to do that?

Comment: I think you did the right thing as it is a question about SVN internals, but for conversational purposes what close reason did you pick? PS: the question in the title and the body of the question don't exactly match up. Are you asking two questions?

Comment: The first off-topic reason, questions about general software etc. As for this question, I'm thinking that answers would be something like: _"Yes, because <answer to the question in the title>"_ or _"No, because <answer to the question in the title>"_.

Comment: Hmya, such questions are certainly not popular.  To draw a parallel, to drive a car you don't have to know how a combustion engine works.  When I got my first one I was very sloppy about changing oil, had no idea that it mattered.  It wasn't until I read up on it and understood to what kind of abuse it is exposed that I concluded I'd better take care of it.  Most likely outcome is that it will get closed because not enough SO users know the engine and don't think the oil matters.  Or dies on the vine because the people that do know think that buying oil is not a very interesting subject.

Comment: Why would a question about SVN internals not be on topic for Stack Overflow, @gimby?

Comment: @CodyGray because its not a practical programming problem. Although what that actually exactly defines is often disputed of course.

Comment: It seems to me like this person has a practical programming problem: *"will SVN store 2 copies of the file internally even though they are identical or does it figure out, that it is a copy and store only 1 file with a total size of 10MB?"* And I can imagine lots of questions about the internals of a tool that would be practical programming problems. Certainly the people who implemented SVN had a practical programming problem. But beyond that, you are taking that section of the FAQ *far* too literally. You can't just wave your hand and say "impractical" to make questions go away. @gimby

Comment: *waves hand* "impractical"

Comment: @CodyGray You see more than me then, which is fine. If I take the faq too literally or you don't take it literally enough is something I don't want to discuss any further here, take 10 meta posts discussing this topic and it goes in all directions. If you think you know the truth, I invite you to answer and we'll see how people vote.

Comment: Questions about software tools commonly used by programmers aren't automatically on-topic, or immune to being closed for any reason. They just aren't automatically *off*-topic, as many people seem to believe, i.e. you don't vote to close a question just because it's about a software tool and not code.

Comment: @CodyGray: "*Certainly the people who implemented SVN had a practical programming problem.*" Yes, but that doesn't mean using it is a practical programming problem. Whether a tool stores files in multiple places or just one with references is a "filesystem storage problem", not a "programming problem". How to use the tool with code files is a programming problem.