# Why do we have tags for off-topic topics?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope, close-reasons

The only difference between the following two questions:

- [How can we avoid 'are the same file' warning message when using 'cp' in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153878/how-to-avoid-are-the-same-file-warning-message-when-using-cp-in-linux)
- [How can I avoid 'are the same file' error when using 'ln' in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77933661/how-to-avoid-are-the-same-file-error-when-using-ln-in-linux)

is that the second is about [ln](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ln) instead of [cp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp). The first is on-topic, the second is not. So apparently the Linux utility [ln](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ln) is off-topic. If the [ln](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ln) utility is off-topic, then why is there a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ln/info) for it?

Can we do something to save people from wasting their time trying to ask questions about such things on SO? Say, by giving a warning if someone tries to use such a tag?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination

Comment: @Robert I see, being off-topic is not sufficient. OK, I guess the best we can do is add a warning to the tag page, which I've done (pending review - if my edits are rejected I'll try something louder).

Comment: We have a python tag. Questions about what your snake needs to eat are still off-topic. Pets.se take those. Same for ln. Maybe there are usages in a strictly programming context but if not the question might fit on Unix & Linux.

Comment: It's also worth noting that some historical questions exist and were, for lack of better words, "allowed" because there wasn't an alternative community. Also, as much as we (as a community) would love to close every off-topic question and stop them getting answers, we do miss some; we are only human. That they exist doesn't mean that a similar topic now is allowed,.or that it was at the time; the rules and guidelines do, and have, evolved over the years.

Comment: @ThomA recently I was asked that same question.  IIRC, I mentioned to a poster that their question was off topic, and then the poster linked a couple of questions similar to theirs and those questions weren't marked off topic.  Kinda makes me thing I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: @Thom Are you saying that both `cp` and `ln` used to be on-topic, but now they're both off-topic? Because now we have Unix & Linux for questions that are strictly about linux utilities?

Comment: @personal_cloud it is more complicated: The current scope of the site as defined in [help/on-topic] and here on meta in [meta-tag:scope] determines whether questions, both new and historic ones, are on-topic here. That a question is on-topic *elsewhere*  is by itself **NOT** a reason for a question to become off-topic here.

Comment: No, my comment is more broad than specifically talking about `cp` and `ln`, @personal_cloud, but I don't doubt they likely would have been before those sites existed. I also, however, stated about that as a community of volunteers we don't close every off-topic question as there's too many compared to the curators. Using the existence of an open and answered question that is off-topic doesn't make other such questions on-topic; it would be like trying to argue to a Police Officer that its OK that you were speeding and drove through a red light, as you saw another driver do it.

Comment: "*Why do we have tags for off-topic topics?*" Because any user over a certain reputation threshold (2,000?) can create new tags, and they don't have to go through a review process before doing so.

Comment: "The first is on-topic, the second is not." That's not true. The first one is currently considered on-topic, the second one is currently not considered that, would be true. You make the fallacy of concluding from single examples about general cases. "Say, by giving a warning if someone tries to use such a tag?" Good idea, but it would be a lot of manual work to mark all these tags. Unless it can be automatized, it might not work out well.

Answer (score 37):

> The only difference between the following two questions... is that the second is about ln instead of cp

Well, no. The first also was asked more than ten years ago, while the second is from just yesterday.

If I take this as a complaint about inconsistent application of policy (and it really seems like one), I have several points to make:

- Policy has changed over the years. Originally, Super User, Unix & Linux SE, etc. didn't exist, and a lot of those questions were considered on topic here that now would not be. (Of course, *some* things that are on topic on those sites are still also on topic here.)
- The vast majority of this work is done by a community of volunteers, many of whom are unaware that there is even a task to perform. Stack Overflow has over 24 million active questions: that is more than triple the number of articles on Wikipedia. That compares to [a few hundred thousand](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1817803) arguably "active" users with the ability to even flag questions, and [scarcely a tenth as many](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1817804) who can vote to close them. Of those, presumably, a large fraction are really only here to answer stuff and collect reputation points (in many cases with complete ignorance as to the site's standards for questions). And those who do close questions are typically far more focused on the influx of blatantly unsuitable new questions from clueless users who don't care about the site's goals or purpose (and who sometimes get an answer anyway). So there are basically no resources available to clean up old questions that are no longer considered to be within the site's purview (not that we'd consider deleting the content this far down the road anyway; of course these questions should be closed, but generally we apply *historical locks* to them afterwards instead.)
- It's a poor look to make a complaint that stems from action taken on your own question, while not preemptively addressing that fact (and either making it into an explicit appeal with a [specific-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specific-question) tag, or acknowledging your "skin in the game" before asking for a policy clarification). It's also a poor look to present the argument as if your thesis is "`cp` is on topic, `ln` is not; this seems arbitrary, but I will go along with it; but I am going to ask them to take action so as not to set traps for me in the future". Seriously, we don't operate like that.

> Can we delete off-topic tags

I wish to challenge the notion that a tag can be "on-topic" or "off-topic" in and of itself. For example, there are any number of questions that I could ask that are demonstrably about the Python programming language, that are clear and unambiguous and could be answered precisely and objectively and would be non-trivial to research - and would still be completely and utterly off topic, as they don't relate to a practical programming problem. Example: "At the time of release of Python 3.0.0, how many people were on the Python core development team?".

On the other hand, yes, some tags tend to attract a very high fraction of off-topic questions. But off-topic questions are not off topic because of their tags; they're off topic **because they fail to meet the [standards outlined in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. Many tags have tag guidance specifically aimed at clearing up what makes a question "about" that subject on- or off-topic.

In particular: questions here about your shell are on-topic when you are writing a shell script (i.e., using your shell's scripting language to write code). They are off-topic when they are about configuring your computer (which includes questions about the semantics of *individual commands*), because **that task is not particular to programmers** - "power users" don't need to be programmers, and they commonly use the same commands to do the same things and that isn't "programming".

(**See also:** [Stop randomly determining questions about server software to be off-topic: write proper guidelines or leave them alone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425628))

This applies to your question: effectively anyone could want to make a symlink, and doing so represents ordinary use of a computer. It is not the application of logic, modelling the real world in data, implementation of an algorithm etc. to solve a practical problem.

Finally: yes, I agree that there are way too many tags in general. There is a process for cleaning up tags with a non-trivial amount (the guideline threshold is 50) of questions, and there are [about 30 thousand](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1817811) such tags - which is way too many, but which also represents an enormous backlog of curation (and *debate*).

Comment: No, I'm not complaining about the closing of my question. It was my fault for forgetting that SO was split into multiple sites. Your point about policy evolution makes sense. It is clear that linux utilities are off-topic due to new SE sites. However, I do not see the existence of a "programming problem" as a major determining factor. For instance, it is still perfectly fine to ask how standard C and Python library functions work on SO, even if there are no surrounding programming problems. Such questions should remain on the mother site (SO) because there's no other SE site for them (yet).

Comment: @personal_cloud In contrast to shell commands, there is no reasonable context where you can use the stdlib functions without programming something, and if there is, it would probably either fall into computer science, unix, math, ProgLangDesign, all of which have their own SE sites.

Comment: @personal_cloud It is also incorrect to categorize SO as the mother site that was split up. WIth new sites, the scope was expanded beyond what was previously reasonable on SO alone, while also taking a few questions that were previously barely ontopic of SO. The point on SO was always that there is a reasonable programming context. Questions about cooking, puzzle solving or creative writing were never ontopic on SO, despite now having SE sites.

Comment: This is a very well-written answer. Most of these "my question got closed but his didn't" Meta posts boil down to one of your first two bullet points. Such questions are about as profound as "why did this movie (filmed in 1975) get a PG rating, but this other movie (filmed in 2015) get a PG-13?" The nature of moderation makes it a bit arbitrary and unstable over time, but no moderation gives you Quora. ‍♂️